# SAP BO - Isolate working hours from ellapsed time

Tags: business-objects, elapsedtime

I would like your support.

In an time period of 1 week (7 days) I would like to isolate the measurements that occur in a time frame between Monday - Friday and from 7:00am to 17:00pm.

I want to **collect the measurements** **only during working hours**.

How can I do this in SAP BO?

Thank you very much.